# Is it possible to publish bot to all teams in my organization?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot deployed on various internal websites using the Directline API. I would now like to deploy to Teams, restricted to our organization (ie not public). I'm aware of how to upload an app to a single team, but we'd like to not have to do this for every single team if possible.

This post asks the same question, but it's quite old now:

[Limit a teams bot to my organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702666/limit-a-teams-bot-to-my-organization)

Is there a way to deploy the bot to teams such that it is available to All teams, but limited to our organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no organization specific distribution mechanism.

Reference: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/issues/72

Edit: (copy of answer from the link)

> @Mikhail2k15, those are great feature ideas. A bot could enforce AAD
>   SG membership itself by requiring the user to log in first, but a
>   top-down way of enforcing this is good.
>
> I will discuss this with the team, but in the meantime please add
>   these as suggestions using UserVoice - click on the Feedback
>   (lightbulb icon) and add these two feature ideas as individual
>   requests so other users can vote on them too (I haven't checked to see
>   that they exist yet - they might).

Comment: I'm on the Bot Framework team, but not the Teams team.  You might get an informed response if you ask here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/issues/72